# Asp.Net GridView HeaderText Delay Update On GridView Column Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChange C#

Tags: c#, gridview, headertext

[image]
I have a gridview Binded on PageLoad(). There is a column with DropDownList. On DropDownList SelectedIndexChange i would need to updated HeaderText of 2 columns.

[image]

As shown above on First time SelectedIndexChange, it's not updating HeaderText of either columns.

[image]

On second time SelectedIndexChange it's updating columns but with previous selected value.

Not updating with currently selected value.

**Below is the code:**

```
    protected void dropdowninsareatype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DropDownList dropDownList = sender as DropDownList;
                string dtext = Server.HtmlEncode(dropDownList.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
                gridViewfacility.Columns[1].HeaderText = Server.HtmlEncode("No Of / " + dtext);
                gridViewfacility.Columns[2].HeaderText = Server.HtmlEncode("Area in Sq Ft. / " + dtext);
                
            }
```

**Page_Load():**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../login.aspx", true);
            return;
        }
        if (Session["udisecode"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../login.aspx", true);
            return;
        }
        if (Session["ip"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../login.aspx", true);
            return;
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PageValidate.Validate(Page);
            checkCSRFGaurd();
            PageValidate.AuthSession(Page);
            // lblUdiceCode.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Session["udisecode"].ToString());
            ((webMaster)Master).LBLPageName.Text = "Area Details";

            PageValidate.CheckSession("udisecode");
            try
            {
                loadareadetails();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('There Is Something Wrong Please Try Again.!!!' )", true);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            //areahall.areaHall();
            //AssingFields();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the PageLoad code?

Comment: @Crowcoder I have updated my question with `Page_Load()` code. kindly check.